# Does webdriver.io waitForVisible method timeout if a new page is loaded?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Using the latest version of webdriver.io (3.1)

I'm running into a weird issue where the waitForVisible method is timing out instantly instead of after the 5000ms timeout I've set. It doesn't always happen and if I add a 500ms pause before the method it seems to resolve the issue. I have a feeling that the waitForVisible method is being called before the new page begins to load after a click and I'm betting that if a page is changed it causes the method to fail and for some reason that failure is being reported as a timeout?

If this is what is happening is there any way around it other than just adding a pause? I don't really like pauses because they seem to make tests fragile.

```
test('clicking logout link logs user out and routes to login view', function(){
        return client.click('#header [data-action="app:logout"]')
        .pause(1000) //This pause fixes the issue
        //This method instantly times out
        .waitForVisible('#login', 10000).then(function(result){
            expect(result, 'Did not log out');
        });
    });
```

Comment: Can you share the code and the page HTML source? This will make it easier to know what is going on & get you help faster.

Comment: Please add some more detail to your question by reading this article [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and following the guidelines.

Comment: Having the same problem. Did you ever figure out what was happening / how to solve it?